# IF statement gives right value but wrong message

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz. When I click on the right answer for the first question, I get the "Correct" message and points added. On the other questions, when I click the right answer, it shows the "Wrong" message but it adds 10 points to the total. I don't understand why it adds the points in the IF statement, but I'm getting the wrong message.

Here is my code:

```js
const questions = [{
    question: "What's Beyonce's middle name?",
    answers: ["Maria", "Giselle"],
    correct: 'Giselle'
  },
  {
    question: "How many children does she have",
    answers: [1, 2, 3],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    question: "What's Beyonce's husband name?",
    answers: ["Phil", "Greg", "Jay-Z"],
    correct: 'Jay-Z'
  },
  {
    question: "How old is Beyonce",
    answers: [34, 45, 27, 37],
    correct: 37
  }
]

questions.map(question => {
  let quest = `
        <p ><span class="number"></span> ${question.question}</p>
        `;
  document.querySelector('.question').insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', quest);
  question.answers.map(ans => {
    let answer = `
        <ul class ="answers">
        <li class="answer">${ans}</li>
        </ul>
        `;
    document.querySelector('p').insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', answer);
  })
})

let number = 0;
document.querySelector('.score').textContent = number;
questions.forEach(quest => {
  document.querySelector('.question').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.className === 'answer') {
      if (e.target.innerText == quest.correct) {
        number += 10;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = number;
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Correct';
      } else {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Wrong';
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Beehive Quiz</h1>
  <h1 class="score"></h1>
  <h4 class="message"></h4>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="questions">
    <h2>On With The Questions...</h2>
    <div class="question"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not the problem. That part of the code is fine. its the other if statement thats the issue

Comment: Your click event isn't associating a question to an answer. `querySelector('.question').addEventListener(...)` - Your `.question` div has 4 event handlers on it. Each click of an answer will check that answer against *all 4 questions*, rather than each question individually.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment, run [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1exat3bg/) **with console open**, and see what I'm talking about. When you click "Giselle" for the first answer, the logic is: *"How old is Beyonce? Giselle. **(wrong)** What is Beyonce's husband's name? Giselle. **(wrong)** ... What is Beyonce's middle name? Giselle. **(Correct)**"* - This is why the first question seems to work properly. It's the last one checked against.